# Including local (JS and CSS) files in local Sinatra Development

Tags: sinatra

I've been trying out Sinatra on my local Windows machine. I want to include some local CSS and JS files. This is how the code looks in layout.erb

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" type="text/css" />
```

All my files are in the same folder as app.rb

This is my app.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  erb :index
end
```

For some reason, I cant see these files included in my pages. When I view the source code and click on the file(JS/CSS) I see that - "Sinatra doesn't know this ditty"- error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Move your static files(css/js) into a folder named `public`. Sinatra looks there with default settings.

If you want to change that behaviour have a look at this: [Static Files](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Static%20Files)

Answer (score 7):

By default Sinatra will look for static files in your `public` folder. You just need to make a folder called `public` in the same directory as your Ruby file, and place your JS and CSS files there.